# Drawing a normal from a point P to a 3d plane

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, plane-geometry

> through the point $P$ you draw a normal to the plane $2x + y-2z + 1 = 0$. Determine the coordinates of the point where the normal intersects the plane that $P$ has the coordinates. $P=(-3
> ,0,2)$

I am new to linear algebra and don't really know what to do here and what equation I should really use.

My initial solution was $2(-3+n)+n-2(2+n)+1=-6+2n+n-4-2n+1=-6+n-4+1=>-9+n=0 = n=9$

$(-3+9, 0+9,2+9) = (6,9,11)$

which is wrong and what the professor said is that I didn't go along the normal so if any one can give me the equation or a help resource that I can use.

Comment: Basically, you find the equation of the line that has the shortest length between the point and the plane. Then you find the coordinates of the point where the line intersects the plane. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal to the plane is $$\left(\begin{matrix}2\\1\\-2\end{matrix}\right)$$ as can be seen from the coefficients of the plane equation.
The equation of the line in the same direction as the normal and which passes through $P$ has equation
$$\underline{r}=\left(\begin{matrix}-3\\0\\2\end{matrix}\right)+\lambda\left(\begin{matrix}2\\1\\-2\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}-3+2\lambda\\\lambda\\2-2\lambda\end{matrix}\right)$$

Solving simultaneously with the plane, we have
$$2(-3+2\lambda)+\lambda-2(2-2\lambda)+1=0\implies\lambda=1$$

Plugging this value into the line equation gives the coordinates of the intersection point $(-1,1,0)$

Answer (score 0):

Let the intersection point be $Q$.  Then $Q = P + t n $ for some $t $.  To determine $t$, find the dot product of the above equation with the normal vector $n$, then you will have,

$Q \cdot n = P \cdot n + t (n \cdot n) $

Now, if a known point $p_0$ is on the plane, then we know that $Q - p_0$ is perpendicular to $n$.  With this in mind, we'll add and subtract $p_0$ from the left hand side of the above equation,

$(Q - p_0 + p_0) \cdot n = P \cdot n + t (n \cdot n )$

This simplifies to

$ (Q - p_0) \cdot n + p_0 \cdot n = P \cdot n + t (n \cdot n)$

The first term on the left hand side is zero because as mentioned above, $(Q - p_0)$ lies in the plane and is therefore perpendicular to the normal vector $n$.  Hence, the equation finally becomes,

$ p_0 \cdot n = P \cdot n + t (n \cdot n ) $

Solving for $t$,

$t = \dfrac{ (p_0 - P) \cdot n }{ n \cdot n }$

Now we can compute $Q = P + t n$

In this problem $P = (-3,0,2) , n = (2, 1, -2)$ and we can pick $p_0 = (0, -1, 0)$

Hence,

$t = \dfrac{ ( (0, -1, 0) - (-3, 0, 2) ) \cdot (2, 1, -2) } { (2, 1, -2) \cdot (2, 1, -2) } $

Simplifying,

$ t = \dfrac{ (3, -1, -2) \cdot (2, 1, -2) }{9} = \dfrac{9}{9} = 1 $

Therfore,

$Q = (-3, 0, 2) + (1) (2, 1, -2) = (-1, 1, 0) $